# JavaFX: Textarea background color error

Tags: css, javafx, colors, background, textarea

Here's the problem:

I tired to make the textarea from javafx have a black color, so i tried to add the parameter:

**"-fx-background-color"** with the value **"black"**

It did change something: Around the text area a black border appeared. I tried to change the background size with:

**"-fx-background-insets"** with the value **"100"** (for testing purposes, i know there are up to 4 values)

But nothing visual happend.

However, if i set the value to "-100", the screen 100 pixels outwards of the textarea is painted black. So, in theory, reversed parameter delivers the reversed result of what i want.

Therefore i ask: Why is it not working? I looked up other solutions, and they do it with the "-fx-background-color" parameter, so what a i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in an external css file:

```
.text-area .content { 
    -fx-background-color: black; 
}
```

don't forget to include this css file, either through FXML or through code. You can use [this tutorial](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/use-external-css-files-javafx/).

Comment: Ok, that worked. Thanks! Still i'd like to know what didn't work there?

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area) - as far as CSS in concerned, `TextArea` is a `ScrollPane`, that has a `Region` (named `content`) inside it. What you did changed the background color of the outer `ScrollPane`, but that is hardly visible, as it is filled entirely by the `Region`.

Comment: Well, now i know. Guess you can't rely on the scene builder as much as you like. I'll keep it in mind if something similar happends again.

Comment: Scene Builder has a very nice (and powerful) CSS analyzer tool. You can use it to highlight controls and even parts of controls to see their CSS path. Go to View->Show CSS Analyzer, and you'll have the option to turn your cursor between normal selection and CSS Path selection.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to change the color of the background of TextArea in JavaFX. Write this in your controller class:

```
textarea.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: black;");
```

I was deep searching on the stackoverflow and eventually found it. The link is given below: [Textarea javaFx Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423200/textarea-javafx-color)

Happy coding!